# Formidable file upload issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, formidable

when I try to upload files using formidable its works fine. but suppose mongoose validation failed user not registered but file uploaded successfully .I need to do something like when user not created file not uploaded .here I put screenshot of my file upload module

```
userController.register= async(req,res)=>{
    // const uploadFolder = path.join(__dirname, "../","public", "profilePic");
    try {
        let form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
        form.multiples = true;
        form.maxFileSize = 50 * 1024 * 1024; // 5MB
        form.uploadDir = uploadFolder;
        form.keepExtensions = true;
        form.parse(req, async(err, fields,files) => {
            try {

                if(err) return res.status(400).send({message:err.message});
                let salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
                let hash = bcrypt.hashSync(fields.sPassword, salt);
                delete fields.sPassword;
                fields.sHash=hash;
                let user = await User.create(fields);
               
                if (!files.sPhoto.length) {
                    if(!user) {
                        return res.status(400).send({message:"User not created"});
                    }
                    const file = files.sPhoto;
                    fs.renameSync(file.filepath, path.join(uploadFolder, file.originalFilename)); 
                    user.sPhoto = file.originalFilename;
                } else {
                    // Multiple files
                }     
        
                await user.save();
                return res.status(200).send({message:"Registerd successfully"});
            }catch (error) {
                errorHandler(req,res,error);
            }   
        });
      
    } catch (error) {
        errorHandler(req,res,error); 
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the form.parse callback the file is already  uploaded, so the easy way would just be to delete it if user is not true

```
if(!user) {
    fs.rm(file.filepath);
    return res.status(400).send({message:"User not created"});
}
```